# Is it possible to define operator[]() (array subscription) outside of the class definition?

Tags: c++

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719):

> The array subscription operator is a binary operator which must be implemented as a class member.

Then it provides an example:

```
class X {
        value_type& operator[](index_type idx);
  const value_type& operator[](index_type idx) const;
  // ...
};
```

Is it possible to define this operator as a member outside of the class definition?

Comment: The only real class _declaration_ is an empty forward declaration.  The code posted above is a class definition, not declaration, and I wanted to know if we could define it outside the class{} block.

Comment: @Bathsheba class *definition* is the correct term here. Note that a class definition is also a declaration, which is nice and confusing.

Comment: Supposing the post you linked is correct, and that is very likly as it is community wiki and often seen, then it is not possible to do so.

Comment: It's possible to _define_ `operator[]` outside of the class definition but it still has to be a class member and therefore _declared_ in the class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can declare it into the class and define it into another translation unit (or same unit) like the following

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myClass {
    public:

    int operator[](int idx);
};

// Definition outside of the class
int myClass::operator[](int idx) {
    return 42;
}

int main() {
    myClass obj;

    cout << obj[55];

    return 0;
}
```

Or something like the following

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h" <--
using namespace std;

int main() {
    myClass obj;

    cout << obj[55];

    return 0;
}
```

**header.h**

```
#pragma once

class myClass {
    public:

    int operator[](int idx);
};
```

**header.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"

// Definition outside of the class
int myClass::operator[](int idx) {
    return 42;
}
```

Just remember the [ODR - One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule): in any translation unit a template, type, object or function shall have no more than one definition.